# No response from FFMPEG from inside php (works in command line)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg

So I have this executable working fine in a Windows 10 dev environment:

```
$cmd = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4';
exec($cmd, $output)
```

However when I move it into the Ubuntu staging environment and change the path to:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

there is no response from it.
The following works in the ubuntu terminal

```
ffmpeg -v, ffmpeg -i, php -v, ...
```

but there is no response from it from inside php.
Am I missing something here?

I've also tried adding sudo to the above command which seems to make no difference.
(Yes I know I should be developing in the same environment as the staging/prod servers but it's not an option in this specific case).

Comment: NOTE: I've also checked the file paths to the audio and video files are correct and has permissions to read/write.

Comment: Try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411988/php-exec-not-working-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Show output of `which ffmpeg`.